# Calculating the volume between 2 surfaces

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I have to calculate the volume between $z = 1+x^2+4y^2$ and $z^2=4x^2+16y^2$ in the half plane $z \le2$.

I have set the bounds as $ -\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} \le y \le\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} $ and $-\sqrt{-4y^2+1} \le x \le \sqrt{-4y^2+1}$.

My problem is that I don't know how to handle the $z\le 2$ part of the problem. Can someone help me understand how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why is $z=1+x^2+4y^2$ and $z^2 = 4x^2+16y^2$? Do you mean $z_1=1+x^2+4y^2$ and $z_2=4x^2+16y^2=4(x^2+4y^2)$ ?

Comment: Okay, and now, what is $z\le 2$? Is it $z=(z_1,z_2)$ und you actually mean $|z|\le 2$?

Comment: You have to subtract the solid $x^2+4y^2=z-1, 1\le z\le 2$ from the solid $x^2+4y^2=\frac{z^2}{4}, 0\le z\le 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z_1=1+x^2+4y^2$ is an [elliptic paraboloid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticParaboloid.html), while ${z_2}^2=4x^2+16y^2$ is a [cone](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cone.html). We can check that the first two surfaces intersect in an ellipse,

$$z_1=z_2 \implies (1+x^2+4y^2)^2 = 4(x^2 + 4y^2) \implies x^2 + 4y^2 = 1$$

which lies in the plane $z=2$. From here we can choose $x\in[-1,1]$ and $y\in\left[-\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2},\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]$.

I suppose "in the half-plane $z\le2$" simply means that $z\le2$. It's easy to show which surface lies above the other by picking any point inside the cylinder $x^2+4y^2\le1$ and comparing the corresponding $z$'s.

The solid can be parameterized by

$$(x,y,z) \in [-1,1] \times \left[-\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}, \frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]\times\left[\sqrt{4x^2+16y^2},1+x^2+4y^2\right]$$

so its volume is

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{4x^2+16y^2}}^{1+x^2+4y^2} dz \, dy \, dx$$

Or, using your order of integration,

$$\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} \int_{-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-4y^2}} \int_{\sqrt{4x^2+16y^2}}^{1+x^2+4y^2} dz\,dx\,dy$$

Consider converting to cylindrical coordinates to make the actual computation a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

The outer volume is

$$V_{\text{outer}}=\int _0^2\int _{-\frac{z}{2}}^{\frac{z}{2}}\int _{-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{z^2-4 x^2}}^{\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{z^2-4 x^2}} dydxdz=\frac{\pi }{3}$$

The inner volume is

$$V_{\text{inner}}=\int _1^2\int _{-\sqrt{z-1}}^{\sqrt{z-1}}\int _{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-x^2+z-1}}^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-x^2+z-1}} dydxdz=\frac{\pi }{4}$$

Hence the volume between the 2 surfaces is

$$V_{\text{outer}}-V_{\text{inner}}=\frac{\pi }{12}$$